# Vector-based editor with symbol library support

Tags: image-editor, vector-graphics, maps

I need a vector graphics editor with support for symbol libraries. So far, I've looked at [xfig](http://www.xfig.org/drawings.html), [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/de/), librecad and LibreOffice Draw.

What I want is something where I can quickly create new symbols from simple shapes, define "snap points" (where other symbols should snap to).

Ideally, I should be able to define the units of the symbol and the drawing to make sure that things have the correct size when I use.

My goal is a tool which allows to quickly create zoomable maps for role playing games, fantasy and SciFi book authors and the like.

My criticisms of the software above:

- xfig is old. It works pretty well but there is no symbol library.
- Inkscape comes close but snapping in Inkscape it brittle at best, [cloning is a pain with a German keyboard](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/1201413), there is no way to define snap points, no real symbol library support and when I'm not careful, then I can clone a clone.
- Draw has a gallery, pretty good snap support (I can define symbols and my own snap points) but support for real world units is bad.
- LibreCad comes even closer but it supports only a single snap point per "block"

Is there something better that I've been missing?

Comment: You can actually [remap Inkscape shortcuts](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Customizing_Inkscape#Change_keyboards_shortcuts) if this may help.